# Oracle Pivot rows into columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, pivot

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
PART_ID  | ATTR_GROUP | ATTR_VALUE1 | ATTR_VALUE2 | COLUMN_NAME
--------------------------------------------------
M2CV4    | GROUP-A    | MATERIAL   |   N/A        |  ATTR_X1
M2CV4    | GROUP-A    | GRADE      |    A         |  ATTR_X2
M2CV4    | GROUP-B    | DOC ID     |   1234       |  ATTR_X1
M2CV4    | GROUP-B    | DOC TYPE   |   XX         |  ATTR_X2
```

I would like to pivot the table to look like:

```
PART_ID | ATTR_GROUP | ATTR_X1 | ATTR_X1_VALUE | ATTR_X2    | ATTR_X2_VALUE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
M2CV4   | GROUP-A    | MATERIAL|   N/A         | GRADE      |  A
M2CV4   | GROUP-B    | DOC ID  |   1234        | DOC TYPE   | XX
```

a part ID can have multiple docs so if M2CV4 has 3 documents then the output would be

```
PART_ID | ATTR_GROUP | ATTR_X1 | ATTR_X1_VALUE | ATTR_X2| ATTR_X2_VALUE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
M2CV4   | GROUP-A    | MATERIAL|   N/A         | GRADE      |  A
M2CV4   | GROUP-B    | DOC ID  |   1234        | DOC TYPE   | XX
M2CV4   | GROUP-B    | DOC ID  |   456         | DOC TYPE   | XX
M2CV4   | GROUP-B    | DOC ID  |   333         | DOC TYPE   | XX
```

Oracle database 12c - 12.2.2 version.
I am giving an example here for 2 columns but I do have a lot more that will get populated based on the group and column_name

Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: What does the *source* data look like for three documents?

Comment: For the 3 documents case, we really need an extra column to distinguish among each of the 3 documents.

Comment: DocID like "AB1" Doc Type like "XCV"
DocID like "XC1" Doc Type like "XCV"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim - I gave a better example above.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - better example above. Thanks Gordon

Comment: Not a better example, actually.  Please show the original source data for the case of 3 documents.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is very similar to the source data. my destination table has x1 | x1_Value | x2 | x2_value ..... etc. the goal is to pivot the table rows to column and assign the values under each attribute like the example I showed above so I can move the data to my destination table

Comment: If you can't respond to my request for my data, then I can't help you, unfortunately.  Gordon gave you a query, but may not over all your edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want duplicates on separate rows.  I recommend using conditional aggregation for pivoting anyway.  If you do so, you can solve the problem using `row_number()`:

```
select part_id, attr_group,
       max(case when column_name = 'ATTR_X1' then attr_value end) as attr_x1,
       max(case when column_name = 'ATTR_X2' then attr_value end) as attr_x2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by part_id, attr_group, column_name order by column_name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by part_id, attr_group, seqnum;
```